# Reading and writing to the file using same try-with-resources

Tags: java, io, filereader, filewriter, try-with-resources

I'm using Java, and I have a method that replaces a value of a parameter in `configFile`. I use try-with-resources so that both will be closed automatically. However, I encounter an unexpected behavior - the `while` loop doesn't read anything from that file because immediately after Java enters the try-with-resources block, `configFile` becomes empty.

```
private static boolean replaceValue(String param, String newValue) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFile));
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(configFile))) {
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isParamPresent = false;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith(param + configDelimiter)) {
                line = line.replaceAll("(?<==).*", newValue);
                isParamPresent = true;
            }
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        if (isParamPresent) {
            bw.write(sb.toString());
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I change to code to be like this below, it works as expected.

```
            if (isParamPresent) {
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(configFile))) {
                bw.write(sb.toString());
                return true;
            }
```

I don't understand what causes `configFile` to become empty. Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: How do you expect to read and write the same file simultaneously?

Comment: You should not be doing reading and writing the same file simultaneously. Instead if the file is small, read all its contents put it in memory -> write the file with the content in memory. If the file is big, write a temporary file simultaneously while reading the file -> do the necessary changes -> delete the original file -> rename the temporary file to old fileName

Comment: @tgdavies Not sure what you mean by simultaneously? Yes, read/write are both in the same method, but they never cross each other. I read line by line. I don't expect any concurrent access to this method either. Writing only will happen when param is found in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileWriter(String fileName)` constructor calls `FileOutputStream(String name)` which sets the `append` flag to false. This means the file will not be opened in append mode.
Based on my testing on windows the file is immediately cleared if the append flag is not set. So in your first variant there's nothing to read, since it was cleared. Your second variant works as it's cleared after you've read the content into your `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of append mode set to false. Note that writing only happens if isParamPresent=true. According to Javadoc, PrintWriter would clean the file immediately after instantiating, but not FileWriter. P.S. it is actually FileWriter(File file).

Comment: @RomanM It doesn't even matter if you actually write. The clear happens after the constructor call already. It's not documented, but happens in the native method call (at least on windows, can't confirm for linux right now).

Comment: I agree that the Javadoc isn't particularly clear.